# How do I share common files in between repositories in git?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have 2 components (A & B) in my project which have their own GIT repositories. These components A & B share a interface (just a single header file interface.h ,lets say). In SVN it is pretty straightforward to share this interface file between 2 repositories without duplicating, by using SVN external properties. How do I achieve the same in GIT. I want to be able to update the interface file from both the repositories in a seamless manner.

I have read about git subtrees, which would involve creating third repo just for one interface file. Such approach is overkill for my scenario. Can anyone suggest easiest solution similar to SVN::external for git ?

Comment: Read about [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: You should think about who has the responsibility over that file. It usually would be kind of unacceptable for *two* repositories to equally be able to change the file. There should be only one that makes *well reasoned* changes to the file, and others should then take a dependency on that. If that means that you need to introduce a third repository just for that one (or maybe other) common files, then that’s how you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) can help in this task.

*Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository.*

Comment: Only works if that directory structure works for your common files.